# "That counts here" meaning

Tags: meaning

There is definition of "That counts here" in online vocabularies like Merriam Webster? I can't find it.

*Usage example*
it is specifically the usage pattern in the code from the outside layer that counts here.

Comment: Compare: *It's the thought that counts*.   That is, that "matters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the fourth sense of Merriam-Webster's definition of the intransitive verb [**count**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counts):

> **4 a** : to have value or significance
> // These are the people who really *count*.
> // His opinions don't *count* for much.
> **b** : to deserve to be regarded or considered
> // a job so easy it hardly *counts* as work

From the [thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/counts):

> **2** to be of importance
> • punctuality and a neat appearance count during a job interview
>
> Synonyms of COUNT
> import, matter, mean, signify, weigh
>
> Words Related to COUNT
> affect, concern, influence, sway
> add up (to), amount (to)
>
> Phrases Synonymous with count
> carry weight, cut ice

In other words, looking at your example sentence:

> It is specifically the usage pattern in the code from the outside layer that *is important* here.

---

Note that the use of *here* isn't part of the meaning of *count*. But if you want to know what it's doing at the end of the sentence, you can replace it with *in this case*:

> It is specifically the usage pattern in the code from the outside layer that is important *in this case*.